# navbar close icon is not working properly

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

After inserting close icon my navbar is not closing properly. When i am clicking on menu in mobile view it is opening the menu item properly. but on close icon click, it's not closing.

CSS:

```
.navbar-toggler>.close {
    display:inline;
}
.navbar-toggler.collapsed>.close, .navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed)>.navbar-toggler-icon {
     display:none;
}
```

Html File-

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top  navbar-custom">
<!--Brand in navigation menu-->     
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="my-1 mx-2 close">X</span>
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i> Menu
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Wall Art</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Frames</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Desk Photos</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Support</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: its working for me when I tried to create a snippet from your code

Comment: but not for me :-(

Comment: do you have more css other than given in the question?

Comment: @kukkez , yes..

Comment: maybe something else is at work here, can you create a snippet that shows the issue, thanks!

Comment: @kukkez, on fiddle is working fine, but there i am getting two buttons... i upload my css there .. https://jsfiddle.net/shreya_js/xbt97pw5/1/

Comment: remove this: `<i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>` https://jsfiddle.net/s5r67qLp/

Comment: Thanks Kukkuz... could you please suggest how can i change the color of navbar according to viewport... i applied breakpoint on bg-dark class. but it's not working as well .. Thanks once again

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/my3oje9t/1/

Comment: Thanks kukkuz.. you resolved both of my issues..I am new in front end developing . Many thanks

Comment: dear kukkuz, I am using jquery for image change on submenu hover it is working properly. but i want to inject some image specific text under the image as well. could you please give some idea. I did something similar using array. is there any other better solution? please see the code for image change on hover. it has problem with main menu default image. Thanks jsfiddle.net/shreya_js/4h7sgpdL/48 –

Comment: sorry for the late reply... bit confused by that, maybe you can post another question in SO and tag `jquery` too?

Comment: Dear kukkuz, thanks but problem has been resolved..